# Activity objects persisting in memory even after calling finish and making the references null

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, retrofit, android-memory

I am making a retrofit enqueue call from SplashActivity and passing data to next activity via bundles.Even after explicitly calling finish on splash activity it still has 48 references in retained heap as seen in MAT.
The app in general is also taking a lot of memory in the background. I debugged and found that my activity's onDestroy() method is getting called, but why are the objects still persistent in the memory? Is it somehow related to the data being passed by reference instead of value? I've been trying to search around the web but with hardly any luck. Please point me if I'm looking in the wrong direction here.

Here's a snapshot of my Splash Activity-

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName();

List<Sport> mSportsList;
List<Event> mEventsList;
List<Carousel> mCarouselList;
WatchOnApiService mWatchOnApiService;

@BindString(R.string.package_name)
String mPackageName;

ProgressBar mProgressBar;
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-8433136449848959~7585529227");

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getSportsAndEventsAndCarousel();
}

private void getSportsAndEventsAndCarousel() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    WatchOnApiService mWatchOnApiService = RetrofitFactory.getRetrofit().create(WatchOnApiService.class);
    final Call<WatchOnSportsEventsCarousel> mCall = mWatchOnApiService.getAllSportsAndEventsAndCarousel(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

    mCall.enqueue(new Callback<WatchOnSportsEventsCarousel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Response<WatchOnSportsEventsCarousel> response, Retrofit retrofit)
        {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (Float.parseFloat(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME) < Float.parseFloat(response.body().getAndroidLatestVersion())) {
                    if (response.body().getAndroidForceUpdate().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                        showForceUpdateDialog();

                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("WatchOn");
                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("WatchOn just got better.Would you like to upgrade ?");
                        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Upgrade",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                        try {                                                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + mPackageName)));
                                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + mPackageName)));
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                beginFlow(response);

                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                } else {
                    beginFlow(response);
                }
            }

            //Response not received something went wrong
            else {
                showAlertDialogNoResponse();
            }
        }

        private void beginFlow(final Response<WatchOnSportsEventsCarousel> response) {

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

            mSportsList = CodeUtils.convertSportsListToLocalTime(response.body().getData().getSports());
            Parcelable wrappedSports = Parcels.wrap(new ArrayList<>(mSportsList));
            mBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.SPORTS_LIST, wrappedSports);
            mEventsList = CodeUtils.convertEventsListToLocalTime(response.body().getData().getEvents());
            Parcelable wrappedEvents = Parcels.wrap(new ArrayList<>(mEventsList));
            mBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.EVENTS_LIST, wrappedEvents);
            mCarouselList = response.body().getData().getCarousels();
            Parcelable wrappedCarousels = Parcels.wrap(new ArrayList<>(mCarouselList));
            mBundle.putParcelable(AppConstants.CAROUSELS_LIST, wrappedCarousels);

            if ((response.body().getLiveSponsors() == 1)) {
                mBundle.putBoolean(AppConstants.LIVE_SPONSORS_AVAILABLE, true);
            } else {
                mBundle.putBoolean(AppConstants.LIVE_SPONSORS_AVAILABLE, false);
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SelectSportEventActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(mBundle);
            mSportsList = null;
            mEventsList = null;
            mCarouselList = null;
            startActivity(i);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            showAlertDialogInternetFail();
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getSportsAndEventsAndCarousel();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: " + mSportsList + mEventsList + mCarouselList);
    alertDialog = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}